# how to get site groups name with SPcontext in client side?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

How Can I get site groups name with using SPcontext in client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();

// Get a particular group
var myGroup = groupCollection.getByName("MyGroup");
```

Answer (score 1):

should be the same as:

server side:

```
SPGroupCollection groups = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteGroups;
```

and client side:

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
```

its grabbing a collection of the current web groups.